# How to generate fields of type String instead of CharSequence using Avro?

Tags: java, apache, serialization, avro

I wrote one Avro schema in which some of the fields ** need to be ** of type `String` but Avro   has generated those fields of type `CharSequence`.

I am not able to find any way to tell Avro to make those fields of type `String`.

I tried to use

```
"fields": [
    {
        "name":"startTime",
        "type":"string",
        "avro.java.stringImpl":"String"
    },
    {
        "name":"endTime",
        "type":"string",
        "avro.java.string":"String"
    }
]
```

but for both the fields Avro is generating fields of type `CharSequence`.

Is there any other way to make those fields of type `String`?

Comment: `String` class implements `CharSequence` interface.

Comment: CharSequence is an interface. By default Avro uses its own Utf8 class as CharSequence implementation. Utf8 is not more than a byte buffer than can be converted into a String using `toString`. Utf8 is convenient when you don't care about the string like in benchmarks... but most often you what to use the CharSequence and you will have to convert it into a String. This is cumbersome and it a 100% memory footprint overhead because the string is now stored both as an Utf8 and as a String. That's why lot of people want String not CharSequence. Mixing both could be useful too.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you want all you string fields be instances of `java.lang.String` then you only have to configure the compiler:

```
java -jar /path/to/avro-tools-1.7.7.jar compile -string schema
```

or if you are using the Maven plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
  <configuration>
    <stringType>String</stringType>
  </configuration>
  [...]
</plugin>
```

If you want one specific field to be of type java.lang.String then... you can't. It is not supported by the compiler. You can use "java-class" with the reflect API but the compiler does not care.

If you want to learn more, you can set a breakpoint in SpecificCompiler line 372, Avro 1.7.7. You can see that before the call to `addStringType()` the schema have the required information in the `props` field. If you pass this schema to `SpecificCompiler.javaType()` then it will do what you want. But then `addStringType` replaces your schema by a static one. I will most likely ask the question on the mailing list since I don't see the point.

Comment: Is there some docs on this? I am looking how I can specify array type. I want it to be Set rather than `java.util.list`, but can't find any docs :/

Comment: it works with 1.8.2 as well. Cheers @Clément MATHIEU

Answer (score 8):

You can set it per field level, just change the type to an object, and include "type" : "string" and "avro.java.string" : "String"

See below for example:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "test",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That is not working. We have avro file defined in that way, and still we get CharSequence instead of String. Mathieu solution with maven configuration works fine in our case.