# Using string instead of java.lang.charsequence

Tags: java, avro

(apache avro 1.8.2, avro-maven-plugin 1.8.2)

I'm having problem with avro:schema.

I declared a field like under below

```
{
            "name": "type",
            "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "java.lang.String"
            }
        },
```

but avro:schema converts like

```
@Deprecated public java.lang.CharSequence type;

...

public OptionDetail(..., java.lang.CharSequence type, ...) {
    ...
    this.type = type;
    ...
  }
```

---

What I tried:

1. `"avro.java.string": "java.lang.String"`
2. (pom.xml, )

```
<stringType>String</stringType>
```

Both of above doesn't work properly. Please let me know what should I try more.
Thanks.

Comment: `CharSequence` is just the interface for `java.lang.String`.  Most likely, your framework is just trying to code to an interface, rather than returning you an implementation.  My advice: maybe don't even attempt what you are doing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I generally agree with you, but if `CharSequence` is the _return_ type of a property (or in this case, of a public field), it'll be a hassle to interoperate with everything else that expects `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading to Avro version `1.10.0`? I don't see the issue in this version. Setting the `stringType` field in the pom fixed it for me, so I expect it's just a version problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all you string fields be instances of `java.lang.String` then you only have to configure the compiler:

```
java -jar /path/to/avro-tools-1.7.7.jar compile -string schema
```

or if you are using the Maven plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
  <configuration>
    <stringType>String</stringType>
  </configuration>
  [...]
</plugin>
```

More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25315412/2945616