# How to convert avro generated Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> to Map<String, String>

Tags: java, spring, avro

I have Avro generated Map that is with Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> type. But my existing method requires Map<String, String> parameter. How can I change Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> to Map<String, String> parameter?

```
public void someMethod(AvroType avroGenObj){
  myMapMethod(avroGenObj.getInput()) // compile error as getInput returns Map<CharSequence, CharSequence>
}


private void myMapMethod(Map<String, String> map){

// to something

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the map and put each key-value pair in a new map, while `toString()`-ing them.

```
Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> map = ...;
Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<CharSequence, CharSequence> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  resultMap.put(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

Or you can do the same using [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

```
Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> map = ...;
Map<String, String> resultMap = map.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().toString(), e -> e.getValue().toString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to cause the Avro schema generator to use `String` instead of `CharSequence` as the mapping for an Avro string; see [How to generate fields of type String instead of CharSequence using Avro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25118727).

Apparently, you can also change the type that Avro uses to represent a string in Java on a per-type basis; see [Avro Schema - what is "avro.java.string": "String"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974241) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35727432/139985.  However, this can be [a source of problems](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2838).  So beware.

If neither of these approaches are going to work for you, then you will need to do a conversion as per @ChaosFire's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75855876/139985).